# How to get the object that existed in all NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have multiple arrays, for example:

```
NSArray *a = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];
NSArray *b = @[@"d", @"a", @"e"];
NSArray *c = @[@"i", @"f", @"a"];
```

As you can see "a" is exist in array a, b, c. I would like to make a function that return the same objet in supplied arrays. So, like this one, I want to get this "a" from them. if all arrays don't have the same object, which will return nil. For example "f" only exist in c, so the function should return nil.

Comment: use your logic. First get the first element from first array and using for loop, iterate the second array and check weather that object is available or not in second array. If available, then iterate third array and check. If available, then return the object. else return nil. In the same method, iterate all other objects in the first array.

Comment: But there maybe 4 or 5 arrays. How to I make this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet new];
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:a];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:b];
NSMutableSet *set3 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:c];


set = [set1 intersectSet:set2];
set = [set intersectSet:set3];

NSArray *allArray = [set allObjects];
```

Comment: but the intersectSet return type is void.

Comment: intersectSet removes from the receiving set each object that isn’t a member of another given set.

Comment: In given answer separate copy of set have been manage so no any kind of intersect removes from the main array.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:a];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:b]];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:c]];

NSArray *intersecArray = [intersection allObjects];
```

this work! from your code it return a in result array

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *a = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];
    NSArray *b = @[@"d", @"a", @"e"];
    NSArray *c = @[@"i", @"f", @"a"];

    NSArray *arraydOfAll=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,b,c,nil];
    NSArray *commonObjArray=[self intersectArray:arraydOfAll];
}



-(NSArray *)intersectArray:(NSArray *)allArray{
  NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:[allArray objectAtIndex:0]];
  for (NSInteger i=1;i<allArray.count : i++){
        [set1 intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[allArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  }
  return  [set1 allObjects]
}
```